# Animação no plano de fundo não funciona no Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Testei o código no Chrome e funcionou normalmente, alguém sabe o que é isso??

```css
body{
 background-image: url("blo.jpg");
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 animation-name: animac;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-duration: 60s;
}
@keyframes animac{
 0%{
  background-image: url("blo.jpg");
 }
 20%{
  background-image: url("bla.jpg");
 }
 40%{
  background-image: url("ble1.jpg");
 }
 60%{
  background-image: url("bli.jpg");
 }
 80%{
  background-image: url("ble.jpg");
 }
 100%{
  background-image: url("blo.jpg");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando a Web Animations API, para criar suas animações. Ela ainda não é padrão para todos os Browsers, [como pode ser visto aqui.](https://caniuse.com/#search=Web%20Animations%20API) A microsoft ainda está considerando a inserção do mesmo em versões futuras do Edge.

Se realmente for necessário ao seu projeto, você pode incluir a API no seu projeto, para utilizar seus recursos. O [Projeto Web Animations API está disponivel no github](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js). Espero ter ajudado.